# Algebra problem : A hint please.

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometry

A sequence of triangles is defined as follows:

$ T_1$ is an isosceles triangles inscribed in a given circle. With one of the equal sides of  $T_1$ as the base , $ T_2$ is an isosceles triangles inscribed in the circle so that the non-coincident vertices of $T_1$ and $T_2$ are on the same arc. Similarly successive isosceles triangles are drawn with preceding triangle's equal side as base . Proceeded this way till infinitum . Prove that as $ n \to \infty$ , $T_n \to $ an equilateral triangle.

My first thought was that their will be a series involved and we have to find the limit of that sequence as n tends to infinity.  But I don't know how to Start wit this problem? Please don't post solution just give me a hint on where should I start and what kind of approach should I have. 
I want to solve this problem on my own with a little hint. 
Thanks .

Comment: What is meant by "on the same arc"?

Comment: When you draw a chord the circle is divided into two parts. So same arc means the same side at which the third vertex of the triangle is.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a_0$ be the base angle of the original triangle $CDE$.  The arc of the circle cut off by the opposite side, $EBD$, is $2a_0$.  Evaluate the base angle of the next triangle from the arc cut off by its opposite side, $EFD$, and call it $a_1$.  Write this as a recurrence and find the limit.

[image]

Comment: I started this way . Let the first base angle is $a_0$ , the base angle of second triangle formed comes out to be$ a_1=  90- \frac{a_0}{2} $ and the third then comes out to be $a_2= 90 - \frac{a_1}{2} $ so the base angle of $ n_{th} $ triangle comes out to be $ 90 - \frac{a_{n-1}}{2}.$ but now what should I do further . ? I tried to bring the base angle in terms of $a_0$ but was not able to think any further .

Comment: Any in your diagram how is angle EBD equal to $ 2a_0 $ it should be $180 - a_0$ ryt?

Comment: $EBD=2a_0$ is a theorem from geometry.  The arc cut by an angle is twice the size of the angle.  Your value for $a_1$ is not correct.  Once you get the right recurrence $a_{i+1}=f(a_i)$, to find the limit $a$ you say $a=f(a)$